# Appending the data in JSON file using Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, hash

I am trying to write/append some data in a JSON file using ruby. I am facing issues while writing data in JSON file in proper format.
I have created and stored my values in temphash. I want to append the content of temphash in existing JSON file. I am doing it in following way:

```
 tempHash = {"Group_Name" => @GroupName, "Group_Logo_Code" => @GroupLogoCode }

 json = File.read('public/group.json')
 secondJsonArray = JSON.parse(json)
 secondJsonHash = Hash[*secondJsonArray]

 jsonHash = []  
 jsonHash << secondJsonHash
 jsonHash << tempHash      

 File.open("public/group.json","w") do |f|
  f.puts JSON.pretty_generate(jsonHash)
 end
```

This is creating malformed JSON. I am not getting the JSON in expected format

Below is what I expect:

```
[ 
 {
  "Group_Name": "Group Name",
  "Group_Logo_Code": "Group Logo code"
 },
 {
  "Group_Name": "Group Name",
  "Group_Logo_Code": "Group Logo code"
 },
 {
  "Group_Name": "Group Name",
  "Group_Logo_Code": "Group Logo code"
 },
]
```

Below is what I am getting:

```
[
  {
    "{\"{\\\"Group_Name\\\"=>\\\"Group Name\\\", \\\"Group_Logo_Code\\\"=>\\\"Group Logo code\\\"}\"=>{\"Group_Name\"=>\"Group Name\", \"Group_Logo_Code\"=>\"Group Logo code\"}}": {
  "Group_Name": "Group Name",
  "Group_Logo_Code": "Group Logo code"
    }
   },
  {
    "Group_Name": "Group Name",
    "Group_Logo_Code": "Group Logo code"
  }
]
```

Please let me know if there is any better way to do this. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Uri Agassi's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23293518/465345) is perfect, but I thought to explain what went wrong in the OP code.

The `Hash[]` expects an array of `key, value` pairs (either as separate arguments or an array of arrays):

```
Hash[:a, 1, :b, 2]        # => {:a=>1, :b=>2}
Hash[[[:a,1], [:b,2]]]    # => {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

But the original JSON contained Array of Hashes which gets parsed into corresponding Ruby objects as in the simplified case:

```
[{:a => 1}, {:b => 2}]
```

When you use the Ruby splat operator `*` on the above array:

```
Hash[ *[{:a => 1}, {:b => 2}] ]
```

You efectively provide separate hashes as a key-value pair to the Hash constructor:

```
Hash[ {:a => 1}, {:b => 2} ]  # => {{:a=>1} => {:b=>2}}
```

So, essentially, you got what you asked for: you turned a array of hashes into a hash of hashes and then you added that to a blank array and topped up with another hash.

**Correct solution**

Just to make the original code work with minimal changes (but still take a look at [Uri's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23293518/465345)):

```
tempHash = {"Group_Name" => @GroupName, "Group_Logo_Code" => @GroupLogoCode }

json = File.read('public/group.json')
secondJsonArray = JSON.parse(json)

secondJsonArray << tempHash

File.open("public/group.json","w") do |f|
  f.puts JSON.pretty_generate(secondJsonArray)
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Laas for proving me the solutions and the wonderful explanation. Uri's code worked fine but I need to check group.json file size which I can do using your code hence I am marking your answer as accepted answer. Thanks a lot once again to both of you... You Guys Rocks... :)

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are doing much too much in this code - why are you trying to convert the array to a hash? Leave it as an array:

```
tempHash = {"Group_Name" => @GroupName, "Group_Logo_Code" => @GroupLogoCode }

json = File.read('public/group.json')

File.open("public/group.json","w") do |f|
  f.puts JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(json) << tempHash)
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Uri Agassi, this is working perfectly fine. I thought I need a hash to push Temphash into...    Anyways this is what I needed. Only thing is sometimes it may happen that group.json file is empty so I need to check its size before parsing it. But thanks a lot once again... :)