# How JSON file is overwritten for every invocation of my ruby method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have tried to write  a JSON file. Every-time a user of my application creates a new patient within rails. My problem with my current approach is that for every time the method is invoked my JSON file is overwritten with a new patient. I want to be able to continuously add to the JSON file without overwritten the existing contents. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

**writer.rb**

```
def self.writes(patient)
      events_json = []
      File.open("public/events.json","w") do |f|
        f.write(patient.to_json)
      end
    end
end
```

**patients_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @patient = Patient.new(patient_params)

    Writer.writes(@patient)
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292530/appending-the-data-in-json-file-using-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify open mode as "a" which will append to the end of the file as specified here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/IO.html#method-c-new

This means that you can change your code to this:

```
def self.writes(patient)
      events_json = []
      File.open("public/events.json","a") do |f|
        f.write(patient.to_json)
      end
    end
end
```

and it should work.

Comment: However, note that JSON is not closed under concatenation, meaning whenever you concatenate two JSON documents, the result will not be a valid JSON document. So, the result of this will not be a JSON file.